# How to run keycloak in idea?

Tags: keycloak

I cloned keycloak (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak.git) from github, opened it in idea, but how can I run it in idea and visit http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/ page?

[keycloak project in idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWlZp.png)

update:

Find KeycloakServer class and run main method，Very simple！

Comment: The README.md has a "Building from Source" paragraph, did you see that?

Comment: Yes, I saw it. But I didn't find the documentation on how to run keycloak in idea.